# Unable to use webservice without fiddler

Tags: c#, soap, fiddler

When I try to use a webservice i got an error which says "Request was cancelled". When I open fiddler and give corresponding settings (defaultProxy, etc.) I can use the webservice successfully. Does anybody experienced something like that? How did you tackle the issue?

Comment: Same problem as mine, check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778141/callback-method-of-webclient-not-firing)

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to initiate the web request?

Comment: What are the response headers, as seen in Fiddler?

Comment: @EricLaw response header has no info, just 500 from my local server, not the remote one, which supplies web service.

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars it is a regular soap thing with basic authentication. Here is the [link](http://pastebin.com/5F1A3g8N) for the code piece

Comment: @Nadeem_MK did you come across any other similar issues?

Comment: @m3sh: The question was "What are the response headers from the webservice when you make the request with Fiddler?" But the best way to figure out what's going wrong is to use Fiddler to capture the web request *from* your server *to* the web service, and compare them to a direct request from the client. My guess is that you'll see one of the headers (e.g. User-Agent) is different.

Comment: Also, are you *positive* that the 500 is coming from the line that issues the SOAP request and not one of the earlier lines (e.g. the ones that try to construct the credential)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I find a way to get over the problem by writing an override for GetWebRequest method of related SoapHttpClientProtocol to turn keep-alive false by default. Roughly adding these lines

```
protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest webRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        return webRequest;
    }
```

on top of reference file (Reference.cs) of related web service solves the issue.